# How to make a CaseInsensitiveConcurrentMap?

Tags: java, concurrency, dictionary, case-insensitive

How can I implement

```
class CaseInsensitiveConcurrentMap<V> implements ConcurrentMap<String , V>
```

which works just like `ConcurrentHashMap<String , V>` except that the keys are compared case-insensitively? The keys should not be converted to lowercase or uppercase.

Note that `Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<String, new MyCaseInsensitiveComparator())` is no solution as it allows no concurrency and misses the additional methods.

Creating a String-like class with case-insensitive `equals` and `hashCode` is no option either, since the map has to be passed to methods expecting strings as keys.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried

```
ConcurrentMap<String, Object> map = 
    new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Object>(
        String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on all your constraints (ConcurrentHashMap) and String keys:

Overwrite any ConcurrentHashMap method and convert any key with key = key.toLowerCase().

Looks like a lot of work, and a lot of unit testing, so if I were you I would try to discuss the interface.

Example:

```
@Overwrite
public void V get(String key) {
  return super.get(transform(key));
}

// Extracted that to avoid cluttering your whole code with that specific transformation
// So you can easily change it
private String transform(String key) {
  return key.toLowerCase();
}
```

Ugly, but, given your constraints, feasible.